I haven't merged my branches to main and now main is way behind. How can I merge all my branches to main?
I've been working on a repository for about a year now and have 23 branches. I'm the only one, no one else is working on this repository. I've always committed my changes and pushed them up to the remote origin on GitHub. I see that each branch is successively ahead of Main, my latest branch is 23 commits ahead of Main. I found this is a problem when I got a new laptop and cloned the repository and noticed that what I got is way behind where I was on my other laptop. What is the best/easiest way to merge all those branches to Main so when I clone the repository I get the latest?
I haven't tried anything yet because I know I can severely screw up this repository so I don't want to ruin it. I don't know if I could just merge the latest branch or do I have to start at the first branch and merge each one?

Are all branches coming from the main branch? Or do you have branches of other branches? If all branches are coming from main, then merge them one by one in the order they were created. Update the next branch from main before merging it. If you have branches of branches, merge into the branch the sub-branches come from, one by one until you only have one or two branches, which you can then merge into main.

I'm not sure where the branches are coming from. I read in a couple of places that I don't need to go back to main to create each branch, so I didn't. Let's say I was fixing a bug and I was on branch-a. When I was finished I could commit the changes and push that commit to the remote. I would then create branch-b and change to that branch and work on the next thing. Does this mean branch-b would be coming off of branch-a instead of main? This is what I did for all of them.

It sounds like you kept branching without ever merging back. Is it right? For example, If you created a branch-b from branch-a, did you merge branch-b back into branch-a after finishing your feature on b?

You're first statement is correct, I kept branching without merging back.

There are ways to display your whole tree of branches (both in the terminal and with GUI tools), it's well documented. And if you have something like main -> a -> b -> c then start by merging c into b, then b into a, then a into main. If one branch have multiple sub-branches, merge them one at a time (from the first to the last) into the parent branch.

I got a graphical view of my branches from 3 different programs: git gui/gitk, GitKraken desktop, and git bash. They all show each branch in a straight line, except for 2 that actually look like the branched to the right. I'm not sure what this means. I ran a "git log --merges" and it doesn't show I merged anything so why wouldn't each branch go further to the right (branch of a branch etc.) and never come back to the main branch? Doing some more research because I'm not sure how to proceed.

I found out that I was creating branches off of main and not a branch of a branch. This made it easy to just merge each branch back to main. I verified everything by cloning the repository on my new laptop and doing a compare of files and folders between my old laptop and new. Everything matched perfectly and now I can work from my new laptop. Thank you @someprogrammerdude for your help and direction.

That's why we're here, to help! :-)
